# How to execute Testng and Maven without testng.xml file

Tags: xml, maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

How to configure pom.xml file so that i can run my test scripts without using testng.xml file? As you know that we can dynamically create testng.xml file using XmlSuite, XmlClass, XmlTest and TestNg object.

```
public class ScriptTest010 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<XmlSuite> suites = new ArrayList<XmlSuite>();
    XmlSuite suite = new XmlSuite();
    suites.add(suite);


    List<XmlClass> classes = new ArrayList<XmlClass>();
    XmlClass clz = new XmlClass();
    clz.setClass(SampleTest.class);
    classes.add(clz);


    XmlTest test = new XmlTest(suite);
    test.setClasses(classes);

    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("username", "mquraishi");
    params.put("password", "nopassword1$");
    params.put("search", "eat pray love");


    test.setParameters(params);


    XmlInclude testLogin = new XmlInclude("testLogin");

    List<XmlInclude> includes = new ArrayList<>();
    includes.add(testLogin);

    clz.setIncludedMethods(includes);


    TestNG testNg = new TestNG();
    testNg.setXmlSuites(suites);
    testNg.run();



}
```

}

Comment: The only things you need to follow is: Naming convention for example `ScriptTest.java`  and add TestNG as a dependency to your project....

Answer (score 4):

Maven will trigger any tests during the `mvn test` lifecycle phase provided you have followed the [Maven Standard Directory Layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) and any test framework or plugin requirements.

For TestNG, you can take a look at using the [Surefire plugin with TestNG](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/testng.html)  which will execute your tests if you follow [surefire's test naming conventions](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html).

Additionally, here's a fairly recent article that goes a bit more in depth with a [TestNG setup example](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/testng/testng-maven-project-example/).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is an acceptable answer but if you are using Eclipse, there is a plugin for TestNG that you can install and then trigger the scripts from Eclipse and it will auto-create the necessary XML files.